# MySQL LEFT JOIN is deleting the column of comparison on fail?

Tags: mysql, database

MySQL table schema: entity (key is entityId), post (key is entityId), photo (key is entityId)

Entity is going to be 1:1 to the combined post+photo tables, as these are basically subcategories of entity

sql request:

```
SELECT * FROM entity
LEFT JOIN post ON post.entityId = entity.entityId
LEFT JOIN photo ON photo.entityId = entity.entityId
```

This does return the full schema, but for entities that do not have a photo, the entityId returned is null. Every row that doesnt have a corresponding photo has its entityId set to null.

QUESTION: What is the cleanest way to combine these subgroups while maintaining all the data? I did manage to do it by doing only one, normal join with posts, and then union-ing that with another entity joined with photos, but my solution is very messy and theres probably a better way to do it.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to list out the columns explicitly.  The problem you are having is the columns have the same name.  For example:

```
SELECT e.*, pid as post_id, ph.id as photo_id
FROM entity e LEFT JOIN
     post p
     ON p.entityId = e.entityId LEFT JOIN
     photo ph
     ON ph.entityId = e.entityId;
```

If the only columns that have duplicate ids are the `entityId` columns, then you can use the `USING` clause (assuming your database supports it):

```
SELECT *
FROM entity e LEFT JOIN
     post p
     USING (entityId) LEFT JOIN
     photo ph
     USING (entityId)
```